# how can a method return 2 widgets which I would later use in a column

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a method that returns a text and a TextInput, instead of using a container I want the widgets to be wrapped easily and sent back, I thought it could be achieved by wrapping the two widgets in `()`:

```
Widget customTextFormField(String hintText) {

    return(
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          "Password",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0
          ),
        ),
      ),
      TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      controller: TextEditingController(text: ""),
      autofocus: true,
      cursorColor: Colors.blue,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

I want this to be used in a Column widget. Using the above code doesn't work as `()` doesn't wrap the two widgets as one. I also used

Comment: You can return a `Column` that contains the two widgets

Answer (score 0):

You either want them to return in a `Column`

```dart
return Column(children: [
  Align(),
  TextFormField()
];
```

or return a `List`, to be used in a column or listview for example

```dart
List<Widget> customTextFormField(String hintText) {
  return [
    Align(),
    TextFormField(),
  ];
}
```

Edit: Returning widgets from methods is considered an anti-pattern. Check this out for more info (watch the video "Widgets vs helper methods"): https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html

> When trying to create a reusable piece of UI, prefer using a widget
> rather than a helper method. For example, if there was a function used
> to build a widget, a State.setState call would require Flutter to
> entirely rebuild the returned wrapping widget. If a Widget was used
> instead, Flutter would be able to efficiently re-render only those
> parts that really need to be updated. Even better, if the created
> widget is const, Flutter would short-circuit most of the rebuild work.

Answer (score 0):

Return a list of Widgets.

```
List<Widget> customTextFormField() {
 return [
  Container(),
  TextFormField(),
 ];
}
```

Use spread operator inside the column

```
return Column(children: [
  ...customTextFormField()
]);
```